# How can I pass a variable into parameter expansion?

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables

I'm checking whether or not environment variables are set.

This gives me exactly what I want in the singular:

```
 : ${API_KEY:?`echo "Need to set API_KEY"`}
```

However, when I extract a function to loop over a collection of variables, things don't work like I'd expect.

```
 function check_env_for { 
   : ${$1:?`echo "Need to set $1 non-empty"`}
 }
 check_env_for API_KEY
```

breaks, returning:

```
 -bash: ${$1:?`echo "Need to set $1 non-empty"`}: bad substitution
```

While a solution is appreciated, what core shell fundamentals am I likely missing?

Answer (score 1):

Along the lines of what you are trying, you can use indirect parameter expansion. This does require a temporary variable, which shouldn't be much of a hardship as this is a function definition:

```
function check_env_for {
    local foo="$1"
    : ${!foo:?"Need to set $foo non-empty"}
}
```

However, note that the error message isn't ideal:

```
$ check_env_for FOO
bash: !foo: Need to set FOO non-empty
```

Since you are writing a function, it's probably clearer to skip the "Display Error" parameter expansion and just test for a non-empty string, again using indirect parameter expansion:

```
check_env_for () {
    [[ -z ${!1} ]] && printf "Need to set $1 non-empty\n"
}
```

Comment: This produces an error locally.  `check_env_for:1: bad substitution`

Comment: Are you sure you are using `bash`? Works for me in 3.2.51

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with the following code, which you can modify to suit your needs:

```
function check_env_for { 
   KEY="$(eval echo \$$1)"
   echo ${KEY:-"Need to set $1 non-empty"}
}
check_env_for API_KEY
```

Here it is in one line:

```
function check_env_for { 
  echo ${$(eval echo \$$1):-"Need to set $1 non-empty"}
}
```

This returns either the value of `$API_KEY` or `Need to set API_KEY non-empty`

Comment: This doesn't echo anything, whether or not the parameter exists as a variable.

Comment: Don't use `eval` to re-implement indirect parameter expansion.

Comment: The `eval` is necessary to obtain the value of the the ENV variable in this context.  This is what `eval` is for.

Comment: If you are using `bash`, `eval` is not necessary. Using `eval` is never a good idea, since it will evaluate whatever is in the expanded variable, not just what you *assume* the contents will be.

Comment: `eval` was created for just such purposes.  Yes, I agree it's not always the best solution, particularly if you don't control your environment, but in this case, based upon the OP, I think it's the right solution.  Sometimes simple is best.

Answer (score 0):

Using `${parameter:?word}` expansion does the trick but the output looks unpleasant. Using `${parameter:-word}` expansion does look better.

If you still prefer the former, your code should look like this.

```
#!/bin/bash
function check_env_for {
        eval : \${$1:?"Need to set $1 non-empty"}
}
check_env_for API_KEY
```

Give this one a try and see if you like it.

```
#!/bin/bash
function check_env_for {
        eval echo \${$1:-"Need to set $1 non-empty"}
}
check_env_for API_KEY
```

The `eval` in both code will evaluate `$1` and expand it to `API_KEY`. The `$` outside of `{}` is escaped therefore it will not be expanded on `eval`.